# RM-11 mounting with COS-11

Tags: microphone-positioning, microphone, field-recording, sanken

What is the standard mounting technique while using the RM-11s? I use topstick and mount it on the clothes in the sweet spot of the chest. Is this correct or is there a better way?

I'm also shooting with ALOT of chef coats, very heavy and lots of rustle. What the best micing technique??

thanks!!!

-SEsound

Answer (score 1):

RM-11 is also great for wedging on the inside of a tie knot with the COS-11 pointing down just hidden by the shadow of the fabric.

The chef's jacket problem may be solved by making two triangle wedges of tape with sticky side out. Place one on the inner part of jacket just below a button, then COS-11, then second wedge and stick it all together so no movement is allowed betwee top layer/mic/bottom layer. Alternate is Joe's Sticky Stuff instead of triangle wedges.

Or try COS-11 in Vclip under the collar.

Or try a B6 in the hairline?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the RM-11 in a common way.

As for chef jackets.. try and get them out in the open.